# difference ways of css property checking Jquery vs regular

Tags: jquery, css

I was wondering what would be the difference in these two codes

```
$('.stars li').each(function(i){

  if(this.style.display !== 'none'){
    this.style.display = 'none';
    return false;
  }
});
```

and this code

```
$('.stars li').each(function(i){

  if($(this).css('display', '')){
    $(this).css('display' = 'none');
    return false;
  }
});
```

why the first one iterate over each li element, however the second one doesn't it stays on the first element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).css('display', '')
```

is an expression that evaluates to a value - what it evaluates to is the `$(this)` jQuery object, which has also had its `display` changed. So the condition

```
if($(this).css('display', '')){
```

will always be satisfied, because objects are truthy.

Use `$(this).css('display') === 'none'` instead (*one* argument) to retrieve the current computed `display` style.

```js
if ($('div').css('display') === 'none') {
  console.log('Div hidden');
} else {
  console.log('Div not hidden');
}

if ($('span').css('display') === 'none') {
  console.log('Span hidden');
} else {
  console.log('Span not hidden');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<span style="display: none"></span>
```

Keep in mind that

```
this.style.display
```

checks the `display` property *on the element itself*, whereas

```
$('div').css('display')
```

checks the *computed* `display` property. The element may have a `display` applied (eg, from CSS like `div { display: none }`) despite not having a `display` property of the element's own `style` object.

Comment: Thank you soo much that was clear enough, so I would say its better to use the this.style.display than $('div').css('display') since the div properties has already css by default which is { display: none }